# Regexp for mysql to detect one '=' and not two '=='

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to detect the following:

```
window.location.href = "http://newlocation.com";
```

but not

```
window.location.href == "http://newlocation.com";
```

the query is ran in mySQL like so:

```
select "blablabla" REGEXP "bla"
```

Can't seem to get my head around this one.

Comment: I came to [^,]location.href\s*[.equals-sign.], but that didn't match.

Comment: Did you try a literal `=`?  i.e. `...\s*=\s*"...`?

Comment: doesn't work in mysql REGEXP... you'll need [:space:] instead of \s. But let me try it with the right syntax. brb

Comment: got it: [^,]location.href[[:space:]]*=[^=]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'window.location.href="http://newlocation.com"' REGEXP "href=\""
```

This gives me 1 (TRUE)

That one also

```
SELECT 'window.location.href="http://newlocation.com"' REGEXP "window\.location\.href=\"http:\/\/newlocation\.com\""
```

It depends what you want to match really.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
SELECT 'window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"' REGEXP '[[:<:]]=[[:>:]]';
```

OR

```
SELECT 'window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"' REGEXP ' = ';
```

Please note that both the above assume that there will be a space before and after the equals sign. If there might be no spaces before or after equals, you can try:

```
SELECT 'window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"' REGEXP '[^=]+=[^=]+';
```

I'm not sure about the last one but it should work.

Hope it helps!